# How to pass the Arraylist of custom Object type from activity to Service using the Parceler library?

Tags: parceler

I have done this in activity.Here **responses** variable is the ArrayList of type custom object LeaseDetailResponse.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(AlarmService.LEASE_DETAIL_RESPONSE_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) Parcels.wrap(responses));
    startService(intent);
```

At AlarmService

```
Parcels.unwrap((Parcelable) intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(LEASE_DETAIL_RESPONSE_LIST));
```

Shows the error

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.parceler.NonParcelRepository$ListParcelable cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.parceler.NonParcelRepository$ListParcelable cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your cast to an ArrayList... Parceler only deals with Parcelable.  You need to use `putExtra()` instead with no cast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
intent.putExtra(AlarmService.LEASE_DETAIL_RESPONSE_LIST, Parcels.wrap(responses));
startService(intent);
```

And to de-serialize in your `AlarmService`:

```
Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra(LEASE_DETAIL_RESPONSE_LIST));
```